# Place a mask on input when user starts typing

Tags: jquery

Hi I'm trying to place a mask on an input using jquery masked input plugin, the input gets a value from a sql query. I need to place a mask on that input when the user starts typing in the input

this is how the input looks:

```
<td><input type="text" name="txt_ssn" id="txt_ssn" data-validation="number" data-validation-error-msg="Invalid SSN" value="<?php echo $var_SSN;?>" data-validation-allowing="-" ></td>
```

and this the jquery code:

```
$('#txt_ssn').on('change focus', function(){

                if ($(this).val().trim().length === 0) {
                $(this).mask("999-99-9999");
                }

            });
```

but after deleting the value of the input there's no mask placed 
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The change event does not fire until you leave the text input field. Instead of listening for a change event, listen for a keyup event. E.g. `.on('keyup...')`